# Conditional Transpose with NAs in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose, na

I've used the dplyr package to summarize some data. The dataframe I produced looks something like this:

```
Iteration   Degree   Proportion
    1          0         .5
    1          30        .7
    1          60        .8
    2          0         .6
    2          30        .9
    3          0         .3
    3          30        .8
    3          60        .8
```

I would like to transform my dataframe into a new dataframe where the each of the 3 degree conditions are their own column, and the corresponding proportion values are filled in. **MOST IMPORTANTLY** I need to impute 'NA' values whenever an iteration does not have a degree value.

The dataframe I am thinking of would look something like this:

```
Iteration  0_Degree  30_Degree  60_Degree
     1        .5         .7         .8
     2        .6         .9         NA
     3        .3         .8         .8
```

Identifying where NAs need to be filled in is the major challenge I am running at the moment.

Does anyone have an idea for how I might accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be achieved with the `spread` function from the `tidyr` package. `tidyr` is part of the the `tidyverse`.

Simply use:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  spread(key = Degree, value = Proportion)
```

The default option for filling missing observations is `fill = 'NA'`.

Comment: Try https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/ . There are great sheets for importing, wrangling, and visualising data :). `tidyr` is in the data import sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Omit `as.data.frame` if you don't need it as a data frame. No packages are used.

```
as.data.frame(tapply(dd[[3]], dd[-3], c))
```

giving:

```
    0  30  60
1 0.5 0.7 0.8
2 0.6 0.9  NA
3 0.3 0.8 0.8
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
dd <- structure(list(Iteration = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    Degree = c(0L, 30L, 60L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 60L), Proportion = c(0.5, 
    0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.9, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: This works great too. Thank you! I appreciate a non-package alternative to the solution. Gives me ideas for how to handle a few other problems I've been working on.